# hfill in align environment, so that the formula is still centered

Tags: math-mode

I would like to use `\hfill` (or it could be a similar command) the same way it works outside the math environment.

Right now I have

```
\begin{align*}
         dw=ddf=0.
    \end{align*} \hfill $\#$
```

But I would like to have the `$\#$` in the line above, because that is the way it is in the rest of the document.

I already tried

```
\begin{align*}
         dw=ddf=0. \hskip0.7\textwidth 
    \end{align*}
```

but then the formula is no longer centered, which is no coherent with the rest of my document.

Comment: Well, I also tried with the $$$$ enviroment, but it also did not work. \w was just a character. I edited it to w

Comment: You can use `\rlap{...}` to attach a component to a line of a display without having its width taken into account.  But here, the `\#` seems more like a label, so `\tag{\#}` may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent
X\dotfill X
\[  dw=ddf=0.\tag*{\#} \]
\end{document}
```

Note you should never use `align*` for single line equations or without `&`.  `\[` or for numbered equations, the `equation` environment, will generally produce better vertical spacing for singe line equations. Without a `&` in an align you only have the left hand side of the equation, so it is set flush right.

`\tag*` produces an alternative label (without `(` `)` for the `*` form)